# Styling site to customer specific based on subdomain

Tags: javascript, css, subdomain, appendto

I am trying to style a site based on the subdomain header used to access the site so for instance it will be:

1. customer1.mysite.com
2. customer2.mysite.com

I have the css files saved for each company on an azure storage location

- https://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/companystles/customer1
- https://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/companystles/customer2

I am trying to get the subdomain and then add the style link to the head of my _layout page but it does not seem to be working can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var subdomain = window.location.host.split('.mysite.com')[0];
            alert(subdomain);
            $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://metalearning.blob.core.windows.net/companystyles/' + subdomain + ' >').appendTo('head');
        });
```

This is correctly giving me back customer1 or customer2 in the alert prompt for subdomain but the link is not being added to the head of the layout page

Comment: Did you forget to add `' + subdomain + '.css` ?

Comment: Some cloud services like AWS or Azure may rename the files when they're uploaded to their storage buckets; this may be the reason why the `.css` extension is missing in the URI.

Comment: extension does not matter here i have tried just 127 in string and this is working, i need to find way to concat the file name to the href

Answer (score 1):

You could try inserting it at the end of your `body` tag.

```
$('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://metalearning.blob.core.windows.net/companystyles/' + subdomain + '>');
```

Does this change work for you?

Comment: $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://metalearning.blob.core.windows.net/companystyles/127" />').appendTo('body');

Comment: this is correctly adding a link to css file called 127 but if i try this with subdomain it is not working after correctly giving me 127 as value of subdomain

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you sure the string you built as URI is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try to append this to the document (just append it do the document body)

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url(css/company1.css);
</style>
```

Edit, i just tried this:

```
$("body").append('<style type="text/css">@import url(css/company1.css);</style>');
```

Seems to work.

Edit 2, how about this?

```
$("body").append('<style type="text/css">@import url(https://metalearning.blob.core.windows.net/companystyles/' + subdomain + ');</style>');
```